# Difficulties to pass a parameter in callback function (Google Map API Markers)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, callback, google-maps-markers

I have a problem with my code. Indeed, I'm trying to give a value of an array as a parameter, but in the callback fonction, the value I get is 'undefined'.

My objective is to create customized markers in function of the category of a place (catLieu) and the type of this place (typeLieu). It works for category but I have difficulties with the type.

This is my code (a part of it):

```
var catLieu;
var typeLieu;
var education =['school', 'university'];

function performSearch() {
clearMaps();
var i;

var clickedEducation = [];
for (i=0;i<education.length;i++)
{
    var checkEducation=document.getElementById(education[i])
    if (checkEducation.checked)
    {
        clickedEducation.push(education[i])
    }
}

if (clickedEducation.length>0)
{
    var caseEdu=[];
    var lieuEdu='Education';
    for (var j=0;j<clickedEducation.length;j++)
            {
                caseEdu[j]=clickedEducation[j];
                var request = {
                    bounds: maCarte.getBounds(), 
                    types: caseEdu[j] // IT DOESN'T WORK
                };
                console.log
                service.radarSearch(request, function (results,status) {callbackExecute(results,status,callback,lieuEdu,caseEdu[j])}); // IT DOESN'T WORK
            }

}



function callbackExecute(results,status,fonctionDeRetour,catPlace,typePlace)
{
    fonctionDeRetour(results,status,catPlace,typePlace);
}



function callback(results, status, catPlace, typePlace) 
{

    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) 
    {
        alert(status); //Message d'alerte zéro résultat
        return;
    }

    catLieu=catPlace;
    typeLieu=typePlace; 

    for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) 
    {
        createMarker(result); // Créer un marqueur pour chaque résultat
    }
    catLieu="";

}
}
```

EDIT : I wrote "var caseEdu[];" but is not the source of my problem.

EDIT2 : The problem is resolved, thanks a lot Dr.Molle :)

Comment: Open your web console (it's somewhere in the browser menus, or press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I [Cmd+Shift+I on a Mac] and choose Console in the dev tools) and you'll find a syntax error: `var caseEdu[];` is invalid JavaScript. There may well be other issues once you correct the syntax error, but before posting an SO question, make sure the code does parse.

Comment: I opened the console but I have no error but the code doesn't work because 'typePlace' in callback function is undefined and types: caseEdu[j] is undefined too.. I see it thanks to breakpoint in debug mode

Comment: If the code runs at all, then the code isn't the code in your question. Again: The code in the question has a syntax error and won't run **at all**.

Comment: EDIT : You're right but it because I make a mistake when I copy the code. In my real code I have "var caseEdu=[]" and it doesn't work
I forgive "=" sorry :)

Comment: Use the "edit" link on the question to fix it. Don't tell me you retyped all the code?! Why not use copy-and-paste and avoid wasting everyone's time (esp. yours)? Remove all code from the question, then use *copy-and-paste* to paste your code in. (If you need to, run it through http://jsbeautifier.org first).

Comment: No I didn't retype all my code but only a part because I wrote a lot of commentary whose decrease the readability of the code

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I just wanted to increase the readability of my code. But my mistake doesn't change anything to my problem. I doesn't understand why I can't set : 
" types: caseEdu[j] " 
and " service.radarSearch(request, function (results,status) {callbackExecute(results,status,callback,lieuEdu,caseEdu[j])}); "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment when  the radarSearch-callback will be executed, the outer loop already has been finished, `j` points behind the end of `caseEdu`.

Possible fix:

replace this line:

```
service.radarSearch(request, function (results,status) {callbackExecute(results,status,callback,lieuEdu,caseEdu[j])});
```

with....

```
(function(edu){
   service.radarSearch(request, 
                       function (results,status) {
                         callbackExecute(results, 
                                         status, 
                                         callback, 
                                         lieuEdu, 
                                         edu);
                       }); 
 })(caseEdu[j]);
```

....now the current item in the loop will be passed as argument

---

### Demo:

```js
var catLieu;
var typeLieu;
var education = ['school', 'university'];

function clearMaps() {
  var markers = maCarte.get('markers');

  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  });
  markers.clear();
}

function performSearch() {
  clearMaps();
  var i;

  var clickedEducation = [];
  for (i = 0; i < education.length; i++) {
    var checkEducation = document.getElementById(education[i])
    if (checkEducation.checked) {
      clickedEducation.push(education[i])
    }
  }

  if (clickedEducation.length > 0) {
    var caseEdu = [];
    var lieuEdu = 'Education';
    for (var j = 0; j < clickedEducation.length; j++) {
      caseEdu[j] = clickedEducation[j];
      var request = {
        bounds: maCarte.getBounds(),
        type: caseEdu[j] // IT DOESN'T WORK
      };
      (function(edu) {
        service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status) {
          callbackExecute(results, status, callback, lieuEdu, edu)
        });
      })(caseEdu[j]);
    }

  }



  function callbackExecute(results, status, fonctionDeRetour, catPlace, typePlace) {
    fonctionDeRetour(results, status, catPlace, typePlace);
  }



  function callback(results, status, catPlace, typePlace) {

    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      //alert(status); //Message d'alerte zéro résultat
      return;
    }

    catLieu = catPlace;
    typeLieu = typePlace;

    for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
      createMarker(result); // Créer un marqueur pour chaque résultat
    }
    catLieu = "";

  }
}

function createMarker(result) {
  maCarte.get('markers').push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: result.geometry.location,
    map: maCarte
  }))
}

function initialize() {


  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    noClear: true,
    markers: new google.maps.MVCArray
  };
  maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(maCarte)
  maCarte.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER]
          .push(document.getElementById('ctrl'));
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(maCarte,'idle',performSearch);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
       body,
       #map_canvas {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0
       }
       label {
         display: block;
       }
       #ctrl {
         background: #fff;
       }
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas">
  <div id="ctrl">
    <label for="school">
      <input id="school" type="checkbox" onchange="performSearch()" />school</label>
    <label for="university">
      <input checked  id="university" type="checkbox" onchange="performSearch()" />university</label>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works !
I decided to use an array because  when the callback will be executed, the  loop already has been finished so I can't use a simple String but I didn't think about the fact that `caseEdu[j]` can not work for the same reason.
You resolve my problem thank you very much :)

Comment: I just understand I don't need an array with your solution a string `caseEdu` is enough (no need of `caseEdu[]`)